# CTE query with subquery is v. slow on small indexed table; how to optimize on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, common-table-expression

I recently rewrote a complicated query as a CTE query with subqueries, partly to learn more about window functions. The new one is very slow; it takes around .5s on fast hardware, for indexed tables of only a few thousand rows. I'm not sure how to interpret the `EXPLAIN`; it seems to indicate that, as I expect, there aren't many rows and there are indexes. What do I need to do here?

This is running on MySQL; this query is being generated by SQLAlchemy, but I originally wrote the core of it by hand in SQL and only then ported it over. The point of this is to find nearby words in a list of words, with some exclusions for a related subject.

```
WITH rowlist AS (
  SELECT
    word.id AS id,
    word.word AS word,
    word.part_of_speech AS part_of_speech,
    row_number() OVER (
      ORDER BY
        word.stripped_word,
        (
          SELECT
            min(quotations.date) AS min_1
          FROM
            quotations
          WHERE
            quotations.word_id = word.id
        )
    ) AS rownumber
  FROM
    word
  WHERE
    word.deleted IS NULL
    AND NOT (
      EXISTS (
        SELECT
          1
        FROM
          word_subject AS word_subject_1,
          word_subject
        WHERE
          word_subject_1.word_id = word.id
          AND word_subject_1.subject_id = 12
      )
    )
)
SELECT
  rowlist.rownumber AS rowlist_rownumber
FROM
  rowlist
WHERE
  rowlist.id = 392
```

The `EXPLAIN` for this is:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1543
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: word
         type: ref
possible_keys: deleted
          key: deleted
      key_len: 6
          ref: const
         rows: 1543
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 4
  select_type: MATERIALIZED
        table: word_subject_1
         type: ref
possible_keys: word_id,subject_id
          key: subject_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 503
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 4
  select_type: MATERIALIZED
        table: word_subject
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: word_id
      key_len: 8
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2415
        Extra: Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: quotations
         type: ref
possible_keys: word_id
          key: word_id
      key_len: 5
          ref: db.word.id
         rows: 4
        Extra: 
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.  A subquery in the `order by` for a window function is quite unorthodox.

Comment: This database holds records for an OED-style dictionary, in which each word has_many quotations. The purpose of this query is to generate a list of words surrounding a particular word. The order of the words is alphabetical ("stripped_word" is the word normalized to lowercase and with no punctuation/whitespace), and if the words are the same, by the earliest quote in the quotations table, hence the subquery in the original order_by.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery has this:

```
    FROM
      word_subject AS word_subject_1,
      word_subject
```

But there's no join condition between word_subject_1 and word_subject. Therefore it's a Cartesian product. You can see that reported in the EXPLAIN as an index-scan (which is practically the same as a table-scan) with an unindexed join "using join buffer".

I don't think you need that join in the subquery at all. In fact, you don't need the correlated subquery either. You can do this as an exclusion join in the CTE, without using a subquery:

```
  FROM
    word
  LEFT OUTER JOIN word_subject
    ON word.id = word_subject.word_id AND word_subject.subject_id = 12
  WHERE
    word.deleted IS NULL
    and word_subject.word_id IS NULL
```

Make sure you have a compound index on the pair of columns in word_subject: `(word_id, subject_id)`.

Comment: Hmm. I do have a compound index on those columns. That subquery is generated automatically by SQLAlchemy, but I use it in many other places and it's extremely fast everywhere else. Let me explore that further....

Comment: The index is needed, but really the point is you need to get rid of the Cartesian product and the correlated subquery. Whether it's generated by SQLAlchemy or hand-coded, it's causing problems.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on it. Tried a bunch of things without success and finally posted asking for help on the SQLAlchemy part. Fingers crossed!